# stacking multiple columns of a data frame to make a single column

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a Data frame as

```
id dep    e1  e2  e3  
 1  x     a   b   c
 2  y     d   e   f
 3  z     g   h   i
```

Now I want to create a column (not in same table) which only consist data like this

```
edu

a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
```

please help me how I can do it R ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
```

Coerce the `data.frame` to `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)
```

Melt it from wide to long, sort by `value` and subset for that column:

```
melt(df, id.vars= c("id", "dep"))[order(value), ][, .(value)]
```

The result is a `data.table` with 1 column and 9 observations:

```
   value
1:     a
2:     b
3:     c
4:     d
5:     e
6:     f
7:     g
8:     h
9:     i
```

If you need a `data.frame` just use `setDF`.

Answer (score 1):

```
c(t(dat[3:5]))
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i"
```

If you want is as data.frame:

```
data.frame(edu=c(t(dat[3:5])))
  edu
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   g
8   h
9   i
```

Comment: can you add bit explanation to it please

Comment: Just pick the columns you want, transpose them and make them a vector by unlisting or by `c`